# Apple developer push notifications APN certificate revoked due to overuse(banned by Apple)?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I recently started using Apples APN for push notifications.
I have all the certificates and the keys correct, and right now im using the developer sandbox platform. Everything was working perfectly, but due to a mistake in one of my scripts, there was a stream of many(around 1 request per minute) connections to the APN SERVERS. So now all my scripts fail to connect and i receive this message:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked in ...
```

I checked all my provisioning profiles and certificates in my apple developer portal and they are all ok(not expired)

Is there an upper limit to the amount of connections i can do on: ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 ??

And if yes, 
1.how do i fix this? 
2.Does apple banned my server ip? Or do i need to do something to my certificates? 
3.Will this problem continue in production?(It is possible that my app may send around 1 notification per minute)

Comment: One notification per minute to a single user sounds abusive to me.

Comment: Not one notification per minute to user, but one connection per minute to apn servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that after nothing worked, i had to create a new app id, and new provisioning profile of course and rebuild. then create a new push certificate and everything works correctly again (so there was no server ban, only certificate revoking)